# How to detect which button is pressed in af:Calendar?

Tags: jsf, calendar, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have implemented an af:calendar in my page. Everything goes fine, apart that I cannot control it, I can not control when the user changes the views of the calendar or when the user moves to a different week or month. Does anyone knows how to detect what operations the user is making with the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything is described pretty well in the documentation.

> The calendar does not fire "high level" events, for example it does
>   not fire specific events for edit, delete, create, context menu, etc.
>   Instead calendar fires the "low level" Calendar and CalendarActivity
>   events.
>
> Let's take a calendarActivity. A calendarActivityEvent will be queued
>   if the user does any of the following on a calendarActivity
>
> ```
> clicks
> right clicks
> focuses and presses a key
> ```
>
> Even though a calendarActivityEvent is queued for all these, you can
>   tell these apart because keyboard, mouse, and triggerType information
>   will also be available in the event.

More details provided [here](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_calendar.html).

If you need something really special, you can always resort to something like jquery to handle UI events and then relay it to the java side.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried this but it just helps me detect that user clicked something but not what, for every click I get the same information ID.. Maybe JQuery can help me further but I thought that something easier should exist.